# How to find out which is the installation account for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a sharepoint site installed and configured on farm. I want to find out which is the account used [spinstall, the user has not used the naming conventions] to do the installation. Is there a way I can find that out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try to check this accordingly to MS user guide:

> It must have domain user account permissions.
>
> It must be a member of the local administrators group on each server
>   in the SharePoint farm, excluding the server running SQL Server and
>   the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server.
>
> This account must have access to the SharePoint databases.
>
> If you use any Windows PowerShell operations that affect a database,
>   the setup user administrator account must be a member of the db_owner
>   role.
>
> This account must be assigned to the securityadmin and dbcreatorSQL
>   Server security roles during setup and configuration.
>
> Membership in the WSS_ADMIN_WPG Windows security group.
>
> Membership in the IIS_WPG role.
>
> db_owner on the SharePoint server farm configuration database
>
> db_owner on the SharePoint Central Administration content database

This should help,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far back the install was done it is very possible there are entries in the windows event viewer under the Applications log.

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts I can read from your message:

1. SharePoint site - i believe most likely you are refering to some Web
   Application that yo u use, even more maybe to the Top-Level site -
   this is not necessarly the same (best practices is NOT to be the
   same - but you could look in IIS for the Application Pool account or
   in the Central Administration > Security for the Acounts used for
   Services and look for the name of the web application - the account used there is teh Identity of the App pool).
2. The actual Farm Configuration account used for the setup of the farm, which, unless changed afterwards it is also the account which is IN the FARM ADMINISTRATORS group. This again could be found quickly in SP-CA under Security.

But neither of these would 100% guarantee (as I said it could have been changed), but the 2nd should get you closer. One other important account is the "Database account" which is asked during installation/configuration of the Farm, basically the account which is used furthermore for the Service Applications - unless again - Powershell is used to install and  various accounts are specified - also find it in the Security > Configure Service Accounts.